# rsync option --log-file seems not to be working

Tags: rsync

I am using the `--log-file` option in rsync to see  the logs. But when I tried to run, it says:

```
--log-file unrecognized option
```

Here is my command:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -av -u --log-file="/sreeni/log.txt" --rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync /sreeni nnmhpt20.ind.hp.com:/sreeni
```

could some one help me with the right syntax ?

I tried these options also.

```
/usr/bin/rsync -av -u --log-file /sreeni/log.txt --rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync /sreeni nnmhpt20.ind.hp.com:/sreeni
```

and

```
/usr/bin/rsync -av -u --log-file="/sreeni/log.txt" --rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync /sreeni nnmhpt20.ind.hp.com:/sreeni
```

Answer (score 0):

Which is your distro?
For an agnostic distro aproach you can use simple output redirection.

rsync **your_chosen_options** >> chosen_logfile 2>&1

which turns into,

```
/usr/bin/rsync -av -u /sreeni nnmhpt20.ind.hp.com:/sreeni >> /sreeni/log.txt 2>&1
```

Anyways for Debian based boxes, this seems to work,

```
rsync -av -u --log-file=/var/log/atest.log SRC DEST 2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

whereas for RHEL I needed,

```
rsync -av -u SRC DEST 1>>/var/log/atest.log 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

this expression works for me (ubuntu 12.10):

```
sudo rsync -axzuvh --force --delete --no-whole-file --log-file=/var/log/atest.log SRC DEST
```

remember using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way works for me:

```
rsync -av /source/directory/ /destination/directory/ &> ~/todaysDate-sync.log &
```